# F# Loop through a list of functions, applying each function in turn to a number

Tags: f#

I've recently started learning F#. I'm attempting to loop through a list of functions, applying each function to a value. For example, I have:

```
let identity x = fun x -> x
let square x = fun x -> x * x
let cube x = fun x -> x * x * x

let functions = [identity; square; cube]
```

I would now like to do something like the following:

```
let resultList = List.map(fun elem -> elem 3) functions
```

where the result value would be the list [3;9;27]. However, this is not what happens. Instead, I get:

```
val resultList : (int -> int) list = [<fun:Invoke@3000>; <fun:Invoke@3000>; <fun:Invoke@3000>]
```

I guess I'm not entirely convinced that using map is the right way forward any longer, so my questions are:

1. Why do I not get a list of numbers?
2. How would return a list of numbers?
3. What does `<fun:Invoke>` mean?

Thanks very much for your help.

Daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your functions aren't quite correctly defined, they're taking an extra (unused) argument and are therefore just partially applied and not evaluated as you're expecting. Besides that, your thinking is correct;

```
let identity2 = fun x -> x
let square2 = fun x -> x * x
let cube2 = fun x -> x * x * x

let functions = [identity2; square2; cube2]

let resultList = List.map(fun elem -> elem 3) functions;;

> val resultList : int list = [3; 9; 27]
```

Although I'm not an F# expert, the `<fun:Invoke>` would in this case seem to indicate that the value is a (partially applied) function.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense! I think I was confusing the two different ways of defining a function. let square x = x * x would also work. Cheers, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Because I like to simplify where I can, you can reduce a bit on Joachim's answer by removing the fun from your functions:

```
let identity x = x
let square x = x * x
let cube x = x * x * x        
let functions = [identity; square; cube]

printfn "%A" (List.map(fun elem -> elem 3) functions)
```

Gives the output `[3; 9; 27]`

For me this is more natural. I didn't understand why the functions themselves needed to *wrap* funcs, rather than simply *be* the function.